# Geolocation API with c++

Tags: c++, geolocation

Is there are any methods to use geolocation api by C++ on Ubuntu 18.04?

Now, **I'm trying to get Lat & Long info by C++, trying to use Geolocation with WIFI**, but it's not that   easy..

Please let me know how to use Geolocation API with C++

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I also searched for a geolocation API and ended up with the simple solution of using ipinfo.io with wget

```
wget -qO - ipinfo.io
```

In C++ you can use this call with popen.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But, using wget with IP address is not that accurate. So, can you recommend other ways? Is it possible to use HTML geolocation api in C++?

Comment: How about using the google geolocation api : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview
This should be more accurate and work same way as ipinfo (wget).